# Why doesn't 'IndexIgnore *' work for 'DirectoryMatch'?

Tags: regex, apache

I am facing a problem where `IndexIgnore *` just doesn't work when regex is used; `Options -Indexes` does.

When an absolute path is used, `IndexIgnore *` works fine.

Do you know why?

---

This is what I have written in my .conf file...

```
<DirectoryMatch "^/var/www/html/example/?$">
  IndexIgnore *
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Comment: Are you trying to match only files that are _directly_ under `/var/www/html/example/` or all files in directories inside that as well?

Comment: Directly under `/var/www/html/example/`. I am now using the regex `^/var/www/html/example/[^/]+/?$` with the same strange behaviour

Comment: Hmmm... that is odd. I think I'll leave this one to someone who knows a bit more about Apache :)

Comment: No worries. Thanks for taking the time to help :)

Comment: It seems to be a bug: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51471

Comment: It's also mentioned in the manual "This directive does not currently work in configuration sections that have regular expression arguments, such as <DirectoryMatch>"

Comment: @covener Can you link to it? I cannot see it in the core manual

Answer (score 0):

`*` is a quantifier, which means it needs something to quantify. To achieve the desired result, use `.*` instead, where the `.` means "match any character" and the `*` means "0 or more times".

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't seem to make any difference. I have tried `IndexIgnore .*`, `IndexIgnore ..`, and `IndexIgnore [file name]` with no joy :( Like I say `Options -Indexes` works, so the regex can't be incorrect

Comment: Hmmm... how strange. If it works with `Options -Indexes`, perhaps that's not using regexes. `*` is definitely _not_ a valid regex, so it could be using globs instead.

Comment: It seems to be a bug: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51471